# Why is $\int\limits_{u}^{u+\omega_j} f'(z)/f(z) dz \in 2 \pi i \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: periodic-functions

Because  $f(u) = f(u+\omega_j)$ for $j \in \{1,2\}$ it applies $$\int\limits_{u}^{u+\omega_j}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz \quad \in 2\pi i \mathbb{Z} \quad \text{for} \quad j=1,2, $$

Hello, I write my thesis at the moment and I really don't understand why the last integral here is in $2\pi i \mathbb{Z}$. I would really appreciate your help!

The function $f$ is elliptic, so $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ are both periods. $u$ is also complex. 
My thought was that it could be connected with the fact that the antiderivative of $\int\limits f'/f$ being $log(f(z))$ ?

Comment: Since $\omega_j$ is a period of $f$, $\gamma \colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ given by $\gamma(t) = f(u + t\omega_j)$ is a closed curve.

Comment: I am at a loss... Is every integral of a closed curve a multiple of $2\pi i$ ?

Comment: No, but you have $$\int_u^{u+\omega_j} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz = \int_0^1 \frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}\,dt = \int_\gamma \frac{dw}{w}.$$ That last integral should look somewhat familiar.

Comment: Cauchy's integral theorem.... thank you very much!!

Comment: Well, I would say "winding number".